# How to know location of process window in relation to screen

Tags: java, awtrobot

I'm attempting to write a bot for a video game. I'm using the Java Robot class, I'm trying to find out how to find the location of the game window in relation to the screen of my pc (the game is not full-screen). I think If I could determine where the game window is, then I could make the appropriate mouse clicks in the x y coordinates for the game. I was also trying to find if Java has a library that lets you attach or hook onto a process to get information from it.

Thanks

Comment: If it’s for a bot, could you make it full screen, or make the screen res the same as the game window (effectively making it full screen)?

Comment: Yeah I also though about doing that, but I wanted to be able to not have it take up my entire screen, such that I could do other things meanwhile.